# iOS convert UTC string to local date

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting UTC string from server. I successfully converted as local string then I try convert it into local date. But date is showing in UTC format. What is wrong with my code?

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:strTime];

NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: utc];

NSDate *localdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds sinceDate:utc];
NSString *local = [fmt stringFromDate:localdate];
NSLog(@"local time%@", local);

NSDate *localDate = [fmt dateFromString:local];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:<Your_UTC_String>];
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *local = [fmt stringFromDate:utc];
NSLog(@"%@", local);
```

Comment: Yeah - I actually quickly took an example. It should actually be the UTC date OP is getting from server.